# World Item Toolips Turned off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Sky Factory and when I started playing it, I had a tooltip appear at the top of the screen showing the % of blocks (like the sieve or barrels for composting), but I think I've hit a key that's turned it off since it's disappeared.

I've no idea what the mod is and tried randomly hitting all keys. Anyone know what it is and how to get it back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mod you are looking for is likely just WAILA (What Am I Looking At?) but I am unaware of a single key to turn it off or on. You generally have to have Numlock on and then hit Numpad 0 and go through the options there to turn it off and/or on.

Assuming that is the right mod, that is where you can go to turn it on again. But the randomly turning it off thing is new to me.

Comment: Wow, don't recall going in to those options at all. I just noticed whilst I was playing it wasn't there anymore. Strange, but thanks, all working now.

Comment: Yeah that is odd.

Answer (score 2):

press 1 on the number pad to turn it on and off.